# Adding a text to speech feature to your android application

Tags: java, android, eclipse, text, speech

I have created a local news app for android mobiles for locals to be able to read the news from. I would like to know if it will be possible to add a feature that will read out the text for the news out loud for readers (mainly the elderly)?

Comment: kind of more generic.. did you do some homework?

Answer (score 0):

There are many tutorials and resources available for that on web. You can do using Text to Sppech Engine,

Here is a great tutorial for that: [Android Text to Speech](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-using-the-text-to-speech-engine--mobile-8540).